# Remove all the rows with same values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, delete-row

I've a matrix like this:

```
1 2 4
4 5 6
1 2 4
7 9 6
1 2 4
```

and i want delete the same rows. 
My new matrix should be

```
4 5 6
7 9 6
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this script may do what you want:

```
B= A;
position = 1;
condition = true;
bSize = size(B,1);
while (position < bSize)
    [~,~,ic] = unique(B,'rows');
    changes = find(ic(position:end,:)== ic(position));
    if (length(changes)>1)
        B(changes+position-1,:)= [];
        bSize = size(B,1);
    else
        position = position+1;
    end
end
disp(B)
```

Comment: great!!! And in case of two matrices? for example: a=[1,2,4;4,5,6;1 2 4;7,9,6; 1 2 4] and b=[3 2 1; 3 4 5; 3 2 1; 4 6 7; 2 8 9] i wanna delete the rows with same values and with the same index too, in order to obtain a1=[4 5 6;7 9 6; 1 2 4] and b1=[3 4 5;4 6 7; 2 8 9]

Answer (score 5):

A more complete solution, based on `unique( ,'rows')` of @tayler would be

```
[uA, ~, ui] = unique(A, 'rows'); % we have a single copy of each row.
% it is now left to determine which row is duplicate 
n = hist( ui, 1:max(ui) );
sel = n == 1; % pick only indices that appear once
uA = uA(sel, :);
```

Comment: I like your solution but it will sort the A matrix which may not be what the OP wants

Comment: @Rasman sorting can be avoided. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911689/how-to-delete-repeated-rows-with-out-re-ordering-them-in-matlab for the use of `stable` option in `unique.

Answer (score 4):

A good spot to start is:

```
b = unique(A, 'rows')
```

Comment: But this doesn't solve the original question. Your solution does not return [4,5,6;7,9,6]. Your soultion would return [1,2,4;4,5,6;7,9,6]

Answer (score 1):

You can try by subtracting one row from all the others and if any row contains all zeroes you know it contains the duplicate elements.