# How to delete repeated rows with out re-ordering them in matlab

Tags: matlab, rows

I have this cell array:

```
levelx=
      'GO:0016787'    'GO:0006412'    'GO:0030533'
      'GO:0008150'    'GO:0006412'    'GO:0030533'
      'GO:0006810'    'GO:0006412'    'GO:0030533'
      'GO:0016787'    'GO:0006412'    'GO:0030533'
      'GO:0008150'    'GO:0006412'    'GO:0030533'
      'GO:0006810'    'GO:0006412'    'GO:0030533'
      'GO:0016787'    'GO:0006412'    'GO:0030533'
      'GO:0008150'    'GO:0006412'    'GO:0030533'
      'GO:0006810'    'GO:0006412'    'GO:0030533'
      'GO:0016787'    'GO:0006412'    'GO:0030533'
```

I need to delete the repeated rows but without changing the order of the whole rows... Note that I used code to find the unique rows but it changes the order of the rows:

```
[~,idx]=unique(cell2mat(levelx),'rows');
unique_levelx =  levelx(idx,:);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
unique(levelx,'rows','stable')
```

Note that in this statement I've assumed that `levelx` is an array because that's how I set up your test data.

Comment: Interesting +1. The `'stable'` option must be a fairly new feature given that [in 2009 Loren wrote a blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/11/26/unique-values-without-rearrangement/) describing a hack to get around the `sort` implicit in `unique`.

Comment: I'm not sure when the 'stable' option was added, but it's present in R2012b.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hack!

```
for li=1:size(levelx,1)
    fn = regexprep( [levelx{li,:}], ':', '' );
    s.(fn) = 1;
end
levelx = {};
fn = fieldnames( s );
for li=1:numel(fn)
    t = regexp( rexexprep( fn{li}, 'GO', 'GO:' ), '(GO:\d+)', 'tokens' );
    levelx(li, 1:3 ) = cellfun( @(x) x{1}, t, 'uni', false );
end
```

Comment: The lengths some people will go to to avoid reading the documentation !

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - I have an old Matlab version the `stable` flag is not documented there. But I enjoyed learning it from your answer, which I +1! Thanks!